# Spring boot thymeleaf <href> URL wrong

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, href

Why my href URL will autofill the word ?

```
     //commodityDetail.html
     <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="commodity">Products</a></li>
```

First URL : http://localhost8080                                   this is correct

Second URL : http://localhost:8080/commodityDetail/commodity       this is wrong

The correct should be http://localhost:8080/commodity

I do not know why does it become " /commodityDetail/commodity "

```
//Controller
@GetMapping("/commodityDetail/{id}")
    public String commodityDetail(@PathVariable Long id,HttpSession session, Model model) {
        CommodityBean commodityBean = commodityService.findCommodityById(id);
        model.addAttribute("commodity", commodityBean);
        model.addAttribute("isLogin", memberService.isLogin(session));

        return "commodityDetail";
```

The correct should be http://localhost:8080/commodity

Other links are correct

```
//Controller
@GetMapping("/commodityAdmin")
    public String commodityAdmin(HttpSession session, Model model) {
        List<CommodityBean> allCommodity = commodityService.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("allCommodity", allCommodity);
        model.addAttribute("isLogin", memberService.isLogin(session));

        return "commodityAdmin";
```

```
//commodityAdmin.html
<li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="commodity">Product</a></li>
```

That URLs are correct

I do not know why the `commodityDetail.html` is wrong

Comment: You should write it as `<a th:href="@{/commodity}">` Please take a look at https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html

Comment: Where is `/commodityDetail/{id}` in your html form

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej You mean this ? `th:href="@{'/commodityDetail/'+${Commodity.id}}"`

Comment: @YuChengLin Yes

Answer (score 0):

If you want a [server relative url](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html#server-relative-urls), you should use the syntax:

```
<li><a th:href="@{~/commodity">Products</a></li>
```

However, since you are not even using `th:href` in this case, the reason that `<a href="commodity">Products</a>` is linking to `/commodityDetail/commodity` is because `href="commodity"` is a [relative url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL#examples_of_relative_urls).  A relative url searches in the subdirectory of the current page.

So if you are currently viewing `http://localhost:8080/commodityDetail/`, any relative urls will be appended to `http://localhost:8080/commodityDetail/`.

Comment: thank you , but why other html are correct ?

Comment: Because it starts with a `/` forwardslash.

Comment: `//commodityAdmin.html   
<li><a href="commodity">Product</a></li>`
This is correct

Answer (score -1):

Thymeleaf provides multiple formats — including context-relative URLs which are relative to the current root directory.

So if your application is configured to use the commodityDetail context path, then the commodityDetail will be the context name utilized in your URLs. Which is why you are are seeing it "auto fill".

For example, if you have the following url:

```
<a th:href="@{/commodity/}">Products</a>
```

Then it will render as the following:

```
<a href="/commodityDetail/commodity/">Products</a>
```

Comment: But here OP don't tell about the context path so how could you define problem is context path

Comment: If you feel you have a better solution, @FaeemazazBhanej, please feel free to post it.